# How do I install more text-to-speech voices on Windows IOT Core?

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-iot-core, dragonboard

My current Universal Windows Application running on the dragonboard 410C is using the default Microsoft Zira TTS through the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis utility.

I know that you can add additional TTS voices on Windows 10 like Microsoft George, Catherine etc. from the settings menu. But how do I install these on the Windows 10 IOT version so that my application can make use of it on the DragonBoard 410C? I want to be able to extend this to use SAPI 5 compliant voices as well. How would I set this up on the dragonboard?